# Expressing 3 to the n with logical operators

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Using logical quantifiers ∀, ∃, as well as ∧, ∨, ¬ and the arithmetic operations +, ×, =, >, <, how can I write an expression φ(n) such that for every natural number n, φ(n)
is true if and only if n is a power of three. (The problem is much harder if you replace “three” by “ten”). Exponentiation and using variables out of scope are both banned.

I tried finding a way to express n = 3^x as a linear function of the basic arithmetic operations, but I am pretty sure that is wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You should include your attempt. Otherwise question likely closed.

Comment: Hint: think about the prime factorisation of $n$.